# insert more than one record from DataGridView

Tags: c#, gridview

This code works with the first row only
and . I want this code  to work with the rest of the rows:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text =orderdetailsDataGridView.Rows.Count.ToString();
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "OD1";
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in orderdetailsDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < orderdetailsDataGridView.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@order_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prod_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@qun", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    x++;


                }
            }
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `x++` twice in the for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to `modify nested structure`

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in orderdetailsDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < orderdetailsDataGridView.Rows.Count; x++)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                           con.Open();
                           cmd.Connection = con;
                           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                           cmd.CommandText = "OD1";
                           cmd.Parameters.Add("@order_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                           cmd.Parameters.Add("@prod_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                           cmd.Parameters.Add("@qun", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                           cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: have you detail of exception Hema

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but I found the error as the last line of code must be   cmd.parameters.Clear();                    and delete the  fir loop

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you have written the proper code.
in foreach loop you are fetching the row, one by one from GridView, then again running an inner loop, with the count of gridview, and in this inner loop, until this loop is dicontinued, you are using the same "row" which you have extracted in foreach loop.
i am not sure, if i am getting this wrong, but ideally this isn't ok.

Comment: 1. foreach (DataGridViewRow row in orderdetailsDataGridView.Rows)
 2.{
 3. if (!row.IsNewRow)
 4. {
 5. cmd.Parameters.Add("@order_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
 6. cmd.Parameters.Add("@prod_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
 7. cmd.Parameters.Add("@qun", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
 8. cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
 9. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 10. cmd.Parameters.Clear();